# Mouse not captured in Remote Desktop session on 2012 R2 guest in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

After restarting a Hyper-V host (Windows Server 2012 R2) I had serious problems with one of the guest VMs (also 2012 R2). The VM was set to save the state, but when the host came back up the VM had crashed and during startup it got many warnings about corruption in the file system. After running checkdisk a couple of times the VM came up and everything looked fine. Connecting to the VM using RDP works like a charm, but if I try to connect to the VM using the "Virtual Machine Connection" in the Hyper-V console the mouse is not captured.

This is the error message I get:

Mouse not captured in Remote Desktop session. The mouse is available in a Remote Desktop session when integration services are installed in the guest operating system.

[image]

I have 5 other VMs running on the same host, none of them have this issue. I have also compared the VM settings and running Hyper-V integration services but I can't find any reason for the mouse problem.

Is there some way to reinstall the integration services on 2012 R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what caused this problem. One of the files for the mouse driver was corrupted (it had a file size of 0). I replaced the file with a copy from another computer, and after a restart the mouse integration works again!

To see your mouse driver files, open the properties for your mouse in Device Manager and select Driver Details in the Drivers tab.

Answer (score 2):

Can you see "Insert Integration Services Setup Disk" in Action tab? If yes, by mounting ISO you will be able to install the integration services and after reboot, the mouse must be available. (Must be available according to Microsoft [reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/manage-hyper-v-integration-services#install-or-update-integration-services)).

However, you can try to create new VM and mount existing VHDX to the new VM. (do it at your own risk)

Comment: Yes I did mount the Integration Servies Setup Disk, but when I run the setup it just says: "This computer is already running the current version of integration services (version 6.3.9600.18907)". Is there some way to force a reinstall?